# SwiftUI View with inconsistent Navigation Bar appearance

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This is the scenario:

1. I'm moving from a UIViewController to a SwiftUI View:

```
let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: DashboardView())
pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

2. On the first time the View's navigation bar will be as expected, when we scroll the screen the bar will be opaque and we won't see the content bellow it:

[image]

3. Now I go back to the previous screen and move to the same Dashboard screen exactly how we are doing it on step #1, but now the content is visible under the navigation bar:

[image]

If I modify the appearance then other screens will have an appearance change as well. One simple example would be screens that didn't have text on their back button now have it.

I've tried this following piece of code a few more things:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

Any suggestions?

This is the body structure for this SwiftUI View:

```
var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                // subviews inside
            }
        }
}
```

EDIT:

Here's the hierarchy:

For the first time we move into the Dashboard:

[image]
[image]
[image]

For the second time we move into the Dashboard:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you do Capture View Hierarchy, how do hierarchies in picture 1 and 2 differ? Also what happens if you set `.navigationBarHidden(true)` on your SwiftUI view? (i.e does it remove navigation bar completely, or do you still see a navigation bar like on second image)

Comment: @flatasearth I've updated the post with the hierarchy, it seems to be identical.
And yes, if I do ```.navigationBarHidden(true)``` then it disappears completely.